# Command-line setting ignored using latexpdf

Tags: python, pdf, python-sphinx

I am using sphinx-build to create both html and latexpdf output. Output looks amazing in both cases.

I would like to pass the **project** name on the command-line so the documentation can be titled e.g., **TEST**. This works great for the html option.  In the example below (from a modified make.bat file), **TEST** overrides any **project** definition in the conf.py file.

```
 %SPHINXBUILD% -b html -D project ="TEST"  %ALLSPHINXOPTS% %BUILDDIR%/html
```

However, the command–line option is ignored when the tex file is created and whatever was in the conf.py is used for the definition of project in the generated PDF file.

```
 %SPHINXBUILD% -b latexpdf -D project ="TEST"  %ALLSPHINXOPTS% %BUILDDIR%/html
```

For example, if **project** is defined in conf.py:   project = 'TEST'

Then used in the preamble:   \title{project}

The document is titled TEST. I cannot seem to override the TEST value with a command-line argument.

Comment: Have a look at: http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/stable/config.html?highlight=build#confval-latex_documents

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the reference to latex_elements. I realize that what I was trying to do, override settings in conf.py on the fly by using command-line arguments, is not going to work.